# Power supply output voltage drift with temperature

Tags: power-supply, drift

The PSU that I've built, output voltage is drifting when it's turned off;

First set values:

[image]

Turned it back on again after 10 hours:

[image]

<sup>*The values being read using a 16 bit ADC and is spot on.*</sup>

The constant current values didn't change but voltage value increased by ~8 mV and started to drop as it's warming up. as I'm writing this, voltage dropped to 3.003.

When it's warmed up voltage stays steady (tested it for 4 hours), so the drift only happens when it's cool down.

Same op amp controlling the voltage is controlling the current too so the drift with temperature is not caused by the op amp because the current value stays steady. also current and voltage each have it's own voltage reference and both are TL431.

The only suspects I can think of is the voltage regulator itself (infamous LM317) and maybe the 10 turn on-board potentiometer.

Problem like this seems common, for example a power supply from Keysight in it's [datasheet](https://www.keysight.com/gb/en/assets/7018-06784/data-sheets/5968-9727.pdf) notes:

[image]

Is this amount of drift considered ok? Is there a way to compensate for it in hardware or software?

<sup><sup>Yesterday I asked this question but had to delete it because I haven't had the long run test result and extra info.</sup></sup>

Comment: *Is this amount of drift considered ok?* Depends on who you ask. If you ask me I'd say it is perfectly OK. But if you ask my neighbor who is an accuracy freak he would say it is completely unacceptable. Different instruments have different requirements, from a $10000 voltage reference you'd expect less drift than from a $100 PSU. What are you using the PSU for? Most circuits don't care if their supply voltage varies 10%. And if a circuit does care then I'd say it's a **bad design**.

Comment: *Is there a way to compensate for it in hardware or software?* Sure, but realize that you will need **a more stable reference to calibrate against**. If you don't have that then how would you know what voltage is correct. Also realize that if the reference voltage of your voltage measurement ADC drifts (are you using the built-in ADC of an Arduino?) you would measure voltage drift even if the PSU's voltage was 100% stable!

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie As a newbie I need to check certain things; did I do it right, is there a need to do that, what's the norm and standard? etc. I need the approval of a experienced person to confirm what I'm doing. if you say it's OK, it's certainly OK. -- It's a 16 bit external ADC, ADS1115. Thank you.

Comment: *what's the norm and standard?* You already found that even a PSU from Keysight can have up to 0.1% + 5 mV (so for 3 .000 V that means 0.3 mV + 5 mV =) 5.3 mV drift over 8 hours. And that's a PSU designed by engineers who know what they're doing and very likely that is also a much more expensive PSU compared to what you have. So a couple of mV drift: I would completely expect that. If it had **no drift at all** I would think you either got very lucky or did something weird. But a general rule in electronics: 5% accuracy is normal, for 1% or better accuracy you need to know what you're doing.

Comment: "When it's warmed up voltage stays steady (tested it for 4 hours), so the drift only happens when it's cool down."  This is normal. User Guide and maintenance manuals for quality items of electronic test and measurement equipment always specify a warm up period for an equipment item for exactly this reason. An equipment item is not guaranteed to operate within its stated performance specifications until after it (i.e., its internal circuits and environment) warms up and reaches its steady-state operating temperature.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie There's a lot of info in your comments, wish you could post it as an answer. I'm going to use a more stable supply for the ADC, thanks for pointing that.